# Does it matter if I wrap a Try/Catch around code inside a function or around the function call?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, try-catch

Is it better to wrap a `Try/Catch` inside a function (around your code) or is it better to wrap it around the function `call`?

Does it make a difference at all?

Consider the code below:

```
function catchErrorInside(){
    try {
         document.querySelector('#element-that-doesnt-exist').style.display = 'block';
    } catch(e){console.log(e)}
}

catchErrorInside();
```

**VERSUS**

```
function catchErrorOutside(){
     document.querySelector('#element-that-doesnt-exist').style.display = 'block';
}

try { 
      catchErrorOutside();
} catch(e){console.log(e)}
```

The error stacks are the same when I tested it. I did find that if I wrapped both the code inside the function AND the function call itself with Try/Catch blocks, the error that's thrown is from inside the function and not from the call.

I've tried looking around in SO and Google but couldn't find any real preferences or pros vs cons. My inkling is that depending on the complexity of the function, you may want to use Try/Catch inside the function as you may want to use try/catch blocks multiple times inside a given function.

Comment: This is a question more suited to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). That said, the latter is better to write tests for and to limit your function to what it *ought* do instead of handle its own error which might complicate things once the function is called from different places and so on.

Answer (score 1):

generally exceptions handling should be placed at the beginning of a call stack (in ur example it's second case). If u place `try`/`catch` block inside some deep rooted `function` in your application, you take away caller's possibility to handle it in own preferred way (unless u would rethrow `Error` inside `catch`, but rethrowing is rarely needed). examples provided by u are senseless, because u log information, which is logged by console anyway without requirement to using `catch` for it.